# the display of the variable value does not change when the variable is changed (Jetpack Compose Android Studio)

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

the application uses mvvm and jetpack compose, the screen (View, compose) shows whether permission has been obtained using the following code:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val access by remember { mutableStateOf(
    NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(context)
        .contains(context.packageName)
    ) }
Text(if (access) "good" else "bad")
```

after that, the settings are opened using:

`context.startActivity(Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"))`

after changing the settings, the old value is displayed on the screen (not updated), but if you go to another screen and open this screen again, the displayed value is updated

1. how make that after changing the settings, the displayed value on the screen is immediately updated?
2. Is it possible to transfer the reading of the parameter of this setting to the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to refresh the Composable as soon as your App comes back to foreground. You initialize the value of `access` to the current preferences, but the value of the variable is not refreshed automatically, because `NotificationManagerCompat` does not return Flow or LiveData. Even if a recomposition happened, you would not get the updated value, because you use `remember`, which saves its state across recompositions.

You can try to refresh the variable whenever the App is brought to foreground again. Use the `onResume` Activity lifecycle callback to detect this. See the following code for example:

```
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val lifecycleState by lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentStateFlow.collectAsState()

val access by remember { mutableStateOf(
    NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(context)
        .contains(context.packageName)
    ) 
}

LaunchedEffect(lifecycleState) {
    if (lifecycleState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED ) {
        access = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(context)
           .contains(context.packageName)
    )
}
```

Note that `collectAsState` requires the following dependency, add it to your module's build.gradle file:

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! I suppose move this logic to viewModel is difficult and impractical?

p.s.
currentStateFlow.collectAsState() requires Lifecycle Runtime Compose 2.7.0
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked! You can mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer. And thanks for the hint regarding the needed dependency, I edited my post to include that info.